# how to make borderless to normalize on drag only in the top of the border

Tags: c#, draggable, borderless

how do i make my borderless form normalize when you are dragging it on the top like you do on browser i had tryed with this

```
 private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            DragMove();

         //   if (WindowState == System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized)

           //     WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Normal;

        }
    }
```

but that normalized it all the time no matter where you clicked on the form

Comment: Surely you'll want to pay attention to the e.GetPosition() return value.  Or the way a window normally works so you don't confuse the stuffing out of your user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve that by making example a transparent label in the top of the form and then use this

```
private void label_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
{
    DragMove();

    if (WindowState == System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized)

        WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Normal;

}
}
```

Comment: that was exactly what i had been looking for